# Delete all records dependent on a deleted reference in morphia?

Tags: mongodb, morphia, cascading-deletes

I have a one to many relationship between foo and bar.  I want to ensure that whenever a foo is deleted all bar that reference it will be deleted as well.  Is there a way to ensure this will happen in morphia?  I can write delete query to look for all dependent objects and remove them as well, but the problem is that the bar objects also have things referencing them that I want to be removed and I would like to ensure the delete logic cascades automatically.

Comment: When you delete a pointer, You will have a NULL reference. So if there are other pointers that points to the same pointer, these pointers will have a NULL reference; they point to nowhere. However if bar pointers are pointing to where foo was pointing or they are both pointing to the same memory location, then bar pointers will continue to make a reference to that same memory. To check bar current reference after deleting, you just need to prints its value. Which should be a null or 0 reference.

Comment: I understand the default behavior, but I don't want the default behavior.  I want all the foo's point to bar to go away entirely when bar does, without having to check bar references or delete them as a separate query.  I presume mongo likely already supports this with optimizations to make it more efficient, because it seems like a common use-case.  I'm not as convinced *morphia* supports it, I couldn't find out how to do it if it does, but thought I would ask to see :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to issue a separate delete call to remove the referenced documents.  Mongo doesn't support relationships nor cascading deletes.  You might consider embedding those documents rather than using references.

Comment: I was afraid you would say this, but I had to ask just in case there was an option.  Thank you for confirming what I suspected.   Embedding may happen eventually, for now I'm trying to minimize changes to an existing mongo structure.  I will keep it in mind for later.